# Добавить один MovieClip в нужный кадр другого

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Есть приложение - мозаика. Хочу сделать, чтобы можно было загружать свою картинку.
Каждое поле мозаики - это MovieClip, находящийся на нужном кадре.
Нужно сформировать новый MovieClip, содержащий по одному полю мозайки на каждом кадре.
Подскажите, как добавить загруженную картинку в MovieClip на нужный кадр.
Пытался сделать так:

```
mc.addChild(img);
mc.nextFrame();
```

Но изображения просто накладываются поверх друг друга.
Так же пытался наследоваться от созданного мной класса, содержащего 16 пустых кадров.
Результат то же.
Вот код:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var img:MC = new MC();   //класс, содержащий 16 пустых кадров
    private var file:FileReference = new FileReference();

    public function Main()
    {
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadFile);
        file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, loadIMG);
        img.gotoAndStop(1);

        img.x = 100;
        img.y = 100;
    }

    private function loadFile (event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        file.browse();
    }
    private function loadIMG (event:Event):void
    {
        file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, putIMG);
        file.load();
    }

    private function putIMG (event:Event):void
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.loadBytes(file.data);
        img.addChild(loader);
        addChild(img);
        trace(img.currentFrame);   /* Кадры меняются, но картинки накладываются 
                                      поверх друг друга */
        img.nextFrame();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-видимому, в actionscript не предусмотрена такая возможность (во всяком случае в документации её нет). Искал долго и много где.
Придется искать альтернативные варианты.
В моем случае это загонять изображения в массив.